# style.display:none turns out to be little dots

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to accomplish a image gallery sliding function. 
I have 8 images in total, one div(image gallery) which can only contain 4 images, 2 buttons on the both sides of the div(image gallery) which can allow you to click to show the next/previous 4 images. 
The images path are populated from database by php and the sliding function is accomplished by javascript(style.display:block & style.display:none).
My problem is why I'm getting 4 small dots on the second page of my gallery? How can I get rid of them? Thanks for help!
Here is **html** code for my gallery:

```
<div class="galleryOuter">
<button class="previous" onclick="showImage(-4)"></button>
<button class="next" onclick="showImage(4)"></button>
<p class="gallery_title">Editor's Choice</p>
<?php
$array=LoadingImages();
foreach($array as $value){
echo"<div class='gallery'>";
echo"<a target='_self' href='#'>";
settype($value['album_id'],"string");
echo"<img class='album_images' src='Images/album/".$value['album_id'].".png' width='330' height='320'>";
echo"</a>";
echo"<div class='desc'>".$value['artist_name']."</div>";
echo"</div>";
} 
?>
</div>
```

Here is the **CSS** code:

```
/*Image Gallery*/
div.gallery{
display:inline-block;
margin:0px 15px 30px 15px;
border:2px solid #999999;
background-color:#fff;
}
div.desc{
font-size:20px;
padding:5px;
text-align:center;
}
div.galleryOuter{
width:101%;
height:50%;
background-color:rgba(242, 242, 242,0.3);
text-align:center;
margin-top:100px;
overflow:hidden;
margin-left:-7px;
min-width:1700px;
overflow:hidden;
}
.galleryOuter:hover{
background-color:rgba(242, 242, 242,0.4);
}
div.gallery:hover{
border:2px solid #ccc;
}
p.gallery_title{
font-size:25px;
}
/*Slider Button*/
.previous{
float:left;
height:475px;
width:50px;
background-size:30px;
background-image:url('Images/icons/leftarrow.png');
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:rgba(242, 242, 242,0.4);
outline:none;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;
}
.next{
float:right;
height:475px;
width:50px;
background-size:30px;
background-image:url('Images/icons/rightarrow.png');
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-color:rgba(242, 242, 242,0.4);
outline:none;
border:none;
cursor:pointer;
}
.previous:hover,.next:hover{
background-color:rgba(242, 242, 242,0.7);
}
```

Here is the **javascript**:

```
function showImage(input_value){
var first_image_index=0;
var first_image_index_af=first_image_index+input_value;
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("album_images");
var y=document.getElementsByClassName("desc");
if(first_image_index_af<0){first_image_index_af=0;}
if(first_image_index_af>4){first_image_index_af=4;}
for(i=0;i<4;i++){
x[first_image_index_af+i].style.display="block";
y[first_image_index_af+i].style.display="block";
x[7-(first_image_index_af+i)].style.display="none";
y[7-(first_image_index_af+i)].style.display="none";
}
}
```

Comment: because you're applying the style to the wrong element

Comment: Are your gallery slides in `<li>` elements? It sounds like you maybe have some default bullet styles you need to remove?

Comment: Can you provide a code

Comment: ask for help to debug without codes, it's like asking to start a car without engine ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I only applied the style.display:none to both images and description, is any one of those caused the problem?

Comment: well .. what are the images contained in

Comment: @moon thanks for commenting, I've updated my question :)

Comment: you'll want to hide the `<div class='gallery'>` ... or maybe the `<a target='_self' href='#'>` .....

Comment: @JaromandaX They are contained in a div called 'gallery' and 'gallery' is contained in a outer div called 'galleryOuter', also each slide contains 4 'gallery'

Comment: @GGO sorry about that. I've updated my question:)

Comment: @JaromandaX I think you are right... I just used the developer tools and I found that each dot is actually a 2*2 div gallery, but how can i hide them?

Comment: yes, I see that, I even suggested you need to apply the CSS to the div with class gallery ... 2 minutes before you told me!!

Comment: by using display:none like you are doing already! but do it on the correct element

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for help, I just figured it out. The solution is commenting the border css in div gallery

Comment: that's a solution, sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is sloved. The right solution is to comment the border css in the div called 'gallery'. It seems that style.display:none applied on border properties will turn out to be dots.